# SQL LocalDb Automatic Instance Startup Failure when called from Visual Studio 2013, but not SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013, localdb

Per MSDN Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx

**LocalDB supports two kinds of instances: Automatic instances and Named instances.**

I suspect this has something to do with my problem, so I am wondering if anyone knows how something like this gets automatically created.  If I can quote from the docs, "One automatic instance of LocalDB exists for every version of LocalDB installed on the user’s computer."

Here is a copy of the relevant section in the above link:

> **Automatic instances** of LocalDB are public. They are created and managed automatically for the user and can be used by any application.
>   One automatic instance of LocalDB exists for every version of LocalDB
>   installed on the user’s computer. Automatic instances of LocalDB
>   provide seamless instance management. There is no need to create the
>   instance; it just works. This allows for easy application installation
>   and migration to a different computer.

Different versions of LocalDB will have different instance naming conventions:

```
SQL 2012 LocalDB = V11.0
SQL 2014 LocalDB = ProjectsV12
```

- I've seen others.

As long as the connecting app's connection string points to the correct instance, all is well:

```
(localdb)\V11.0
(localdb)\ProjectsV12
```

If I try to connect with SQL Server Management Studio to either instance (localdb)\V11.0 or (localdb)\ProjectsV12, **I CAN, the "stopped" server "autostarts"**.

If I set the SQL Server instance in VS2013 to either instance (localdb)\V11.0 or (localdb)\ProjectsV12, **I CANNOT, the "stopped" server "fails" to start. It attempts to start, but fails.**

Here is the error message found in the instance error.log indicating why the instance start failed.

```
014-12-19 15:12:14.09 Logon       Error: 17828, Severity: 20, State: 3.
2014-12-19 15:12:14.09 Logon      The prelogin packet used to open the connection is structurally invalid; the connection has been closed. Please contact the vendor of the client library. [CLIENT: <named pipe>]
```

I may have found a clue here:

On one of my machines where Automatic Instancing works, the sqllocaldb command outputs following:

```
C:\>sqllocaldb info v11.0
Name:               v11.0
Version:            11.0.3000.0
Shared name:
Owner:              AM\Z617699
Auto-create:        Yes            <-- Yes? - and I have no idea how this is set.
State:              Stopped
Last start time:    12/18/2014 5:18:46 PM
Instance pipe name:
```

On one of my **other** machines where Automatic Instancing does NOT work, the sqllocaldb command outputs following:

```
C:\>sqllocaldb info v11.0
Name:               v11.0
Version:            11.0.3000.0
Shared name:
Owner:              AM\Z617699
Auto-create:        No              <-- No? - and I have no idea how this is set.
State:              Stopped
Last start time:    12/18/2014 5:18:46 PM
Instance pipe name:
```

I have spent days trying to find the answer to this question. Here is a link to an MSDN forum post that outlines all the unsuccessful steps I have taken to resolve this issue:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/83ad45d5-15c3-4463-bc0c-6c4899bf947e/localdb-visual-studio-2013-will-not-automatically-start-the-sql-2014-localdb-projectsv12-instance?forum=sqlexpress

The workaround is to just start the instance manually before you start VS2013.  I'm just trying to resolve this issue so I can get an "Automatic Instance" image for all our developers.

I hope you just know he answer. :-)

Thanks, Dave

Comment: The 2014 automatic instance name is MSSQLLocalDB (ProjectsV12 is created by SSDT)

Comment: I have 2012 local db installed, i also have 2 instance, 1 named "v11.0" another 1 named "projects", the later one is Auto-Create=Yes, i have no idea of it, but just leave it and work fine.

Answer (score 28):

I had the same issue.
I resolved it by deleting and recreating the instance from command line:

1. Open the command line
2. Delete the session by typing: sqllocaldb delete "v11.0"
3. Recreate the instance with: sqllocaldb create "v11.0"

The new instance allows auto creation, and solves the issue.

The solution was taken from:
http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/sqlserver/sqlexpress.aspx?ID=8bcb5f1e-0240-4df3-8a5e-7e3e73e1c45b

Comment: Works also when using Visual Studio 2015 environment.  It said in Event manager that "LocalDB parent instance version is invalid: MSSQL12E.LOCALDB" and I did that stuff with MSSQLLocalDB-instance etc.  It created new version and prints out LocalDB instance "MSSQLLocalDB" created with version 13.0.1100.286. Nice

Comment: Nice, solved a headache for me. Best to start with sqllocaldb info to get the name right. In my case it's MSSQLLocalDb.

Comment: @blearyeye I was looking for a list command and completed looked over this. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't been able to connect to mssqllocaldb, and after 3 hours of uinstalling, reinstalling, repairing etc I was nearly ready to reformat windows. Turns out all I had to do was your 3 steps. Dunno why any of the sql install programs with their multiple "preinstall" checklists etc couldn't fix it

Comment: For me, (v2016); merely `sqllocaldb delete "MSSQLLocalDB"` was sufficient - I suspect automatic instance (special name, MSSQLLocalDB), is re-created when required.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on VS2015 and SQL2016
the problem my dev station is a laptop, project explorer i think uses tcpip connection, while SQLeplorer local file or so.

It worked after i made sure that SQL used the Network card, and that it had a cable plugged in (so SQL could server the request over TCP using that IP) which it couldnt over wifi (by default?)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. One of the problem may be an older installed version of this product. Try to delete the database instances which are located in the following folder:

> C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft
>   SQL Server Local DB\Instances\VeeamEndPoint

After that it works for me!!!