# How do I get CodeMap in VS2013 to run against a SQL Server 2014 Express instance?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2013, automated-tests

Due to another project I was working on last week I had to load SQL Server 2014 Express. The problem I have now is that this appears to have broken the CodeMap tools. The project compiles ok and when the XML is written out it attempts to access the V11.0 version of `(localdb)` prior to showing the base classes desired.

Under Tools/Options there is a setting for pointing to the proper data base which I set as follows:

[image]

After rebooting VS2013, the problem still exists.

I then added an app.config file like this: Per the [other S.O. posts here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154763/visual-studio-code-map-unable-to-connect-to-the-specified-database):

[image]

But when running right clicking on a class and picking Show in Code Map I see the class, but if I attempt to include base classes I see this error.

[image]

SSMS shows this:

[image]

And VS2013 Server Explorer shows this:

[image]

All I want is for CodeMap to work with my current SQL Server 2014 Express version.

Comment: Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577659/sql-localdb-automatic-instance-startup-failure-when-called-from-visual-studio-20?rq=1 , it seems your VS is now trying to connect to a 2014 instance. Prior to installing 2014, it was probably using a 2012 version. 2012 needs `(localdb)\V11.0` in place of `(localdb)\ProjectsV12`. Swap your connection to use `(localdb)\V11.0` and see if that gets it all working again.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion I changed the connection string back to V11.0 and it did the same thing.  Probably because there is no version V11.0 on the system.

Comment: When Visual Studio 2013 installed, it put SQL Server 2012 Express on the machine. Now you have 2014 on the box "properly", rather then just a local install/copy. So I figured CodeMaps is looking for its "old" database file handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Go here and re-install SQL Express 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062) 
[image]

It fixed this problem immediately! I must have done an upgrade or 2014 did it automatically.

P.S. Make sure to check the install (localdb) check box when installing.